# "Merge" style operation with literal values?

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table containing a student-grade relationship:

```
Student   Grade   StartDate   EndDate
   1        1    09/01/2009    NULL
   2        2    09/01/2010    NULL
   2        1    09/01/2009   06/15/2010
```

I am trying to write a stored procedure that takes `Student`, `Grade`, and `StartDate`, and I would like it to

1. check to make sure these values are not duplicates
2. insert the record if it's not a duplicate
3. if there is an existing student record, and it has a `EndDate = NULL`, then update that record with the `StartDate` of the new record.

For instance, if I call the procedure and pass in `1`, `2`, `09/01/2010`, I'd like to end up with:

```
Student   Grade   StartDate   EndDate
   1        2    09/01/2010    NULL
   1        1    09/01/2009   09/01/2010
   2        2    09/01/2010    NULL
   2        1    09/01/2009   06/15/2010
```

This sounds like I could use `MERGE`, except that I am passing literal values, and I need to perform more than one action.  I also have a wicked headache this morning and can't seem to think clearly, so I am fixating on this `MERGE` solution.  If there is a more more obvious way to do this, don't be afraid to point it out.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a `MERGE` even if you are passing literal values. Here's an example for your issue:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertStudentGrade(@Student INT, @Grade INT, @StartDate DATE)
AS
BEGIN;

    MERGE StudentGrade AS tbl
     USING (SELECT @Student AS Student, @Grade AS Grade, @StartDate AS StartDate) AS row
     ON tbl.Student = Row.Student AND tbl.Grade = row.Grade
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT(Student, Grade, StartDate)
       VALUES(row.Student, row.Grade, row.StartDate)
    WHEN MATCHED AND tbl.EndDate IS NULL AND tbl.StartDate != row.StartDate THEN
      UPDATE SET
        tbl.StartDate = row.StartDate;

END;
```

Comment: Oh, excellent.  I didn't know you could use literal values with `MERGE`! I tried something similar, but didn't think to use the aliases, which seems obvious now.  This isn't quite exactly what I need, since I need to insert and update when matched, but I'm sure I can work out a solution there. The real crux of it was how to use `MERGE` with my values. Thanks much!

Comment: You could also use something like this:

USING (VALUES (@Student, @Grade, @StartDate)) AS [row](Student,Grade,StartDate)

Comment: @Davos I'd really like to see your comment in an answer.

Comment: Thanks @yzorg , but I think Lamak has answered every aspect of this question (unlike the other answer below which does not), my contribution here was pretty minor. If anything it could be and extension of this answer.

Answer (score 27):

I prefer the following, it is cleaner and easier to read and modify.

```
MERGE Definition.tdSection AS Target
USING
    (SELECT *
     FROM   ( VALUES
            ( 1, 1, 'Administrator', 1, GETDATE(), NULL, Current_User, GETDATE())
             ,( 2, 1, 'Admissions', 1, GETDATE(), NULL, Current_User, GETDATE())
             ,( 3, 1, 'BOM', 1, GETDATE(), NULL, Current_User, GETDATE())
             ,( 4, 1, 'CRC', 1, GETDATE(), NULL, Current_User, GETDATE())
             ,( 5, 1, 'ICM', 1, GETDATE(), NULL, Current_User, GETDATE())
             ,( 6, 1, 'System', 1, GETDATE(), NULL,Current_User, GETDATE())
             ,( 7, 1, 'Therapy', 1, GETDATE(), NULL, Current_User, GETDATE()) 
            )
            AS s (SectionId
                  ,BusinessProcessId
                  ,Description, Sequence
                  ,EffectiveStartDate
                  ,EffectiveEndDate
                  ,ModifiedBy
                  ,ModifiedDateTime)
     ) AS Source
ON Target.SectionId = Source.SectionId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (SectionId
           ,BusinessProcessId
           ,Description
           ,Sequence
           ,EffectiveStartDate
           ,EffectiveEndDate
           ,ModifiedBy
           ,ModifiedDateTime
           )
    VALUES (Source.SectionId
           ,Source.BusinessProcessId
           ,Source.Description
           ,Source.Sequence
           ,Source.EffectiveStartDate
           ,Source.EffectiveEndDate
           ,Source.ModifiedBy
           ,Source.ModifiedDateTime
           );
```

Comment: This doesn't answer question the OP asked about writing a stored procedure, which takes parameters to be inserted. This also ignores part 3 of the question regarding updates when the end date is null. This example will only insert new records, and as such is not really any better than an insert statement.

Answer (score 14):

Simply:

```
--Arrange

CREATE TABLE dbo.Product
(
    Id   INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(40),   
)
GO

--Act

MERGE INTO dbo.Product AS Target 
USING 
(
    --Here is the trick :)

    VALUES 
        (1, N'Product A'),
        (2, N'Product B'),
        (3, N'Product C'),
        (4, N'Product D')
) 
AS 
Source 
(
     Id,
     Name
) 

ON Target.Id= Source.Id

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 

INSERT 
(
      Name
) 
VALUES 
(
      Name
);
```

Comment: Thank you. You save me a lot of time. It's a good trick to use MERGE instruction and take advantage of clean syntax when you do not have actually 2 tables to merge, but literals or variables instead.