# SQL Server MERGE without a source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I am learning how to use SQL Server MERGE statement from this page:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

```
MERGE dbo.FactBuyingHabits AS Target
USING (SELECT CustomerID, ProductID, PurchaseDate FROM dbo.Purchases) AS Source
    ON (Target.ProductID = Source.ProductID AND Target.CustomerID = Source.CustomerID)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.LastPurchaseDate = Source.PurchaseDate

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (CustomerID, ProductID, LastPurchaseDate)
    VALUES (Source.CustomerID, Source.ProductID, Source.PurchaseDate)

OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*;
```

However all the examples I can find (such as the one above) are using an actual table as Source. Is it possible to directly pass the data? I would rather not create a temporary table for that (if possible and recommended?)
How would the query above be modified?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to pass the data directly just for practice purposes as you learn how to use merge?

Comment: No I was thinking of allowing the user to update/insert the data without having to create a new table each time... Is that not recommended? Otherwise if 2 users try to merge at the same time, I need to have rules to create unique temporary table names and it starts to be a mess.

Comment: You don't need to manage the naming of temporary tables. SQL Server automatically makes sure that multiple sessions creating a temporary table of the same name don't conflict. http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables

Comment: no need to create unique temporary table for different user just use Local temporary tables using # it will not found in another transaction. and sql will also manage if two user enter same records.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this format:

```
MERGE TARGET_TABLE AS I
USING (VALUES ('VALUE1','VALUE2')) as s(COL1,COL2)
ON I.COL1 = s.COL1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
```

You could also reference this: 
["Merge" style operation with literal values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980669/merge-style-operation-with-literal-values)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
Declare @customerID int = 1;
Declare @productID int = 1;
Declare @purchaseDate date = '1900-01-01';

MERGE dbo.FactBuyingHabits AS Target
USING (SELECT CustomerID = @customerID, 
    ProductID = @productID, 
    PurchaseDate = @purchaseDate) AS Source
  ON (Target.ProductID = Source.ProductID AND Target.CustomerID = Source.CustomerID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.LastPurchaseDate = Source.PurchaseDate
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (CustomerID, ProductID, LastPurchaseDate)
    VALUES (Source.CustomerID, Source.ProductID, Source.PurchaseDate)
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed an even simpler version and came to this solution:

```
MERGE Target_Table
USING (VALUES (0)) as s(x)
ON last_run is not null
WHEN not matched then
insert (last_run) values(getdate())
when matched then
update set last_run=getDate();
```