# Is there a way to use MERGE in HANA without a source table?

Tags: merge, hana

I'm trying to use MERGE, in HANA, to insert, or update a table without a second table as a source. This must be done in one command, no store procedures.  Also, UPSERT won't work in this case.

I found this answer for SQL, but HANA doesn't seem to like VALUES in the USING clause.

[SQL Server MERGE without a source table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479233/sql-server-merge-without-a-source-table)

Here is the answer for SQL from the post above:

MERGE TARGET_TABLE AS I

USING (VALUES ('VALUE1','VALUE2')) as s(COL1,COL2)

ON I.COL1 = s.COL1

WHEN MATCHED THEN
...

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`MERGE INTO`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.03/en-US/3226201f95764a57810dd256c9524d56.html) command is specifically designed for ETL-type use cases where data from one table should be *merged* into another table and its data in there. A single tuple insert is possible via a subquery like so:

```
select * from t;  -- single integer column 'C'
insert into t values (2);

c
-
2
```

**merge command, inserting 4 or updating matches to 100**

```
merge into t
      using (select 4 c from dummy) s 
      on t.c = s.c
   when matched then 
        update set t.c = 100
   when not matched then 
        insert values (s.c);

c
--
2
4
```

**run the merge command again**

```
c
--
2
100
```

So, that works just fine.

As for the [`UPSERT/REPLACE`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.03/en-US/20fc06a7751910149892c0d09be21a38.html) command using `VALUES` is perfectly possible and even explained in the command examples in the reference documentation.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.