# How to write MERGE query using SELECT FROM VALUES in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, merge, google-bigquery

I want to write `MERGE` query using literal values in `BigQuery` database.
I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35659674/5659025 (version for SQL Server) but BigQuery returns the error: "Table-valued function not found"

Is it possible to make it in `BigQuery` and how?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you want to do in BigQuery? So I can help you write your query. Also, according to the documentation _"A MERGE statement is a DML statement that can combine INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations into a single statement and perform the operations atomically."_ LINK: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Let's suppose that we have a table with columns "Name" and "Value" and row ("Alex", 10). I want to merge literal values ("Alex", 15) and ("Dmitry", 20). The result in db should be: ("Alex", 15), ("Dmitry", 20). The best way for this in SQL Server would be using `MERGE` command between db table and literal values. The problem is that I cannot (or don't know) how to do it in BigQuery

Comment: Ok, I see. So, the merge function is used to UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT rows in a table. According with what you said it appears you want to unite all the rows from two tables. If this is the issue, you can use UNION ALL statement, as follows : *Select Name, Value from table_a UNION ALL Select Name, Value from table_b*. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: can you give me an update if it was what you expected?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes no, you did not understood me correctly. I want to merge table with literal values (values that are hardcoded in the query)

Answer (score 0):

After our discussion in the commet section, I can suggest you two options:

First, using  the [INSERT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_statement) statement. According to the documentation:

> Use the INSERT statement when you want to add new rows to a table.

Therefore, you modify the rows in your source table. I have used a dummy data to reproduce it. My source data base was:

[image]

In the BigQuery UI, the syntax is as follows:

```
insert `source_table` (email, content)
select "ale@gmail.com" as email, "add something" as content
```

or

```
insert `source_table` (email, content)
select "ale@gmail.com" , "add something"
```

Notice that I used double quotes because the field I am adding is a *String*. And the output is as below:

[image]

The Second option is to use [UNION ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-expression_1). I would like to point that with this option your are not updating or modifying your source table, instead you are creating a view with new data added. The syntax is as below:

```
SELECT 'aleee@gmail.com' , "add something 2" UNION ALL
--#if you want to add more rows to your view, you will need to write another 
--#select 'email@gmail.com.br', "something " UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM  `test-proj-261014.sample.foobar`
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is totally wrong. The main goal was to do it with `MERGE` statement. The first option will not work because it only inserts without upsert. You can aprove my linkedin request and I'll describe you an issue if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

Given an existing table:

```
create table if not exists test.my_table (
  name string,
  value int64
);

insert into test.my_table (name, value)
values ('alex', 10);
```

You can merge new values using `UNION ALL` and many `select` statements.

```
merge into test.my_table t
using (
  (select 'alex' name, 15 value)
  union all
  (select 'dimitri' name, 20 value)
) s
on t.name = s.name
when matched then update set t.value = s.value
when not matched then insert row;
```

You need the `select` to name the column, you need to name the column to do the join (ie. `on t.{column} = s.{column}`.

Another (less verbose) alternative is to unnest an array of struct, where the names of the columns come from the name of the struct fields:

```
merge into test.my_table t
using (
  select * from unnest((
    select ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, value INT64>>[
      ("alex", 15),
      ("dimitri", 20)
    ]
  ))
) s
on t.name = s.name
when matched then update set t.value = s.value
when not matched then insert row;
```